# How to use DistributionLambda layer to return the mean and variance of a multidimensional output (Tensorflow Probability)

Tags: tensorflow, confidence-interval, tensorflow-probability

I have an LSTM model that takes some number timesteps of a multidimensional ('n' dimensional) variables, and predicts the next timestep (so the output is an 'n' dimensional vector). I was trying to use tensorflow probability to predict a distribution over predictions; specifically, I was interested in the mean and variance of the predicted distribution, so I can use this to create a confidence interval. The model looks something like this:

```
  # Negative log likelihood loss function
  neg_log_lik = lambda y, rv_y: -rv_y.log_prob(y)

  # The LSTM architecture
  model_lstm = Sequential()
  model_lstm.add(LSTM(units=125, activation="tanh", input_shape=(n_steps, n), return_sequences=False))
  model_lstm.add(Dense(units=n*2, activation="relu"))
  model_lstm.add(tfp.layers.DistributionLambda(
    lambda t: tfd.Normal(loc=t[..., :n], 
                         scale=0.01*tf.math.softplus(t[..., n:]))))
  
  # Compiling the model
  model_lstm.compile(optimizer="RMSprop", loss=neg_log_lik)
```

I was hoping it would return 'n' means and 'n' variances (hence the units=n*2 in the dense layer before the DistributionLambda layer), but it seems to just return an 'n' dimensional vector at the end (when I do model.predict(); interestingly, when i print out the model summary it shows something like this:((None, n), (None, n)), but finally the actual output shape is just (batch_size, n)) when i make a prediction.

I was wondering why this is the case, and if there is a way to get the mean and variance of each dimension in the output?

I am quite new to tensorflow probability, so do let me know if I'm not explaining things correctly.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: i think if you just call `model(some_input)` you'll get back an instance of the Normal distribution that you're constructing.

The distributions that DistributionLambda layers return are registered with the TF `convert_to_tensor` registry. If you pass these distributions into some op that expects a tf.Tensor, the distribution will be "tensorified" -- the default method is `dist.sample()` but you can change this with an argument to DistributionLambda (see docs). I think `model.predict(...)` is probably invoking this behavior at some point, but calling the model directly should not.